# Strange behaviour- mongoDB GORM

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a Grails application using Grails 2.3.8 and Mongo GORM plugin 3.0.1 . I have a service which constructs an object during its first invocations and saves it in mongoDB and returns it. In subsequent invocations, it would just retrieve the constructed object from the mongoDB and return it.

```
    def loadWeekData(String startDate,String storeId){
    def weekJson = WeekJson.findByStoreIdAndStartDate(storeId,startDate)

    if(weekJson==null){
        //construct weekJson here
        weekJson.save(flush:true)
        weekJson=WeekJson.findByStoreIdAndStartDate(storeId,startDate)
    }


    weekJson
  }
```

WeekJson domain class has other nested objects with hasMany relation. `WeekJson` hasMany `Employee` which hasMany `Day` which hasMany `Planned` which hasMany `Activity`

**WeekJson domain class**

```
    public class WeekJson{
    static hasMany = [employees:Employee]
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static mapping = {
    employees fetch: 'join'

    }
    String toString()
    {
    "$employees"
    }

  }
```

**Employees domain class**

```
    public class Employee {

static mapWith = "mongo"
static hasMany = [days:Day]

static mapping = {
    days fetch: 'join'
    }
    String toString()
    {
    "$days"
    }
    }
```

**Day domain class**

```
    public class Day {

 Planned planned;
 static mapWith = "mongo"
 static constraints = {
 planned nullable:true
 }

 String toString()
 {
     " plan: $planned "
 }

 static mapping = { planned lazy:false}
    }
```

**Planned domain class**

```
     public class Planned {

List<Activity> activities
static hasMany = [activities:Activity]
static mapWith = "mongo"

static mapping = {
    activities lazy:false
   }

String toString()
{ activities }
}
```

**Activity Domain class**

```
    public class Activity {
    String inTime;
String outTime;
double duration;
String type;
String desc;
static mapWith = "mongo"
static constraints = {
    duration nullable:true
    type nullable:true
    desc nullable:true
}

String toString()
{
    "$inTime to $outTime"  
}
}
```

I have changed fetching behavior to eager in all the classes with hasMany relations.

The first time, all the nested objects are constrcuted properly, saved in mongoDB, and the returned object is correct.

However, for the next call, `Activity` objects are null. I've verified that the nested objects are still present in mongoDB during this call. Records in the `Planned` collection have `id`s to `Activity` collection records .

When I do,

```
   println weekJson.employees.days.planned.activities
```

the list of `Activity is printed. However,

```
    println weekJson
```

gives `Activity` list null and so does rendering as Json.

Why is GORM not retrieving the nested objects the second time around ? 
Is it possible that this a problem of GORM being unable to handle relationships with this level of nesting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should switch to `sub-documents` in your domain model.

Btw, if you want to help us help you, post more data on your case: which version of mongo, grails etc. you are using? what your domain classes look like? what do you see in the mongo collections upon saving?

Comment: I have added a skeleton of my domain classes and the relevant verison info

Comment: I don't think, that mongo is the right choice for your app. You have tooooo many relations between objects. Switch to a SQL db and let your relations be managed properly

Comment: Also, my appilcation requires me to use references to the `Activity` records rather than embedding as a sub-document, since it will be reused across other collections

Comment: right. I stand by my point. With all respect to NOSQL databases, the relations is one thing what the SQL DB can do way better.

Comment: It's even not about mongo-GORM (which *might* have problems with deep-linking). it's about the mongo and other NOSQL DB (Neo4j is the exception) itself. In a document-oriented DB the references are rather exceptional, and the main goal of such DB's is to provide the best possible performance on semi-structured data in a single collection

Comment: Thank you, we started with mongoDB as a kind of fast cache for our responses, and using references seemed like an easy way for maintaining consistency across related objects. Embedding or moving to RDBMS seems sensible now.

Comment: you can use `polyglot persistence` in your project: store models with relations in a RDBMS, and flat data in the mongo. Thus you get the best of both worlds

Comment: Its working fine with sub documents . We do use RDBMS for some domain classes already BTW